# Split Large string Google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am working with SOQL via google sheets script. One of the fields I am retrieving is of type TextArea and contain quite a bit of mixed information. It returns a Large string as below

```
fullDescription:
"First name: Peter Last name: Pan Email: Peter@pan.com Company name: someCompany How can we help? : Looking to get some app testing done across iPhone and Android devices. Job Title: Cofounder
```

Ideally I just need the following info out of that string

Company name:

Email:

What I have tried is a series of substr commands, to break it out piece by piece but it is not accurate 100% of the time.

```
   var cutEmail = splitStr.substr(splitStr.lastIndexOf("."));
   var trimCompany = cutEmail.substr(cutEmail.indexOf(":")+2,cutEmail.lastIndexOf(" "));
   submitCompany= trimCompany.substr(trimCompany.indexOf(""),trimCompany.lastIndexOf("How"));
```

There is very likely a much better and more consistently accurate way to achieve this, but it has not yet come to mind.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you can rely on the string always containing the expected labels in the expected order, then you can use `indexOf` with those labels - for example, `indexOf('Company name:')`, `indexOf('How can we help?')`, and so on. If you account for the length of the leading label, you can isolate the content in between the two labels. It's basically the same as the approach you are already taking, but with more specific `indexOf` values.

Comment: If that is not possible, then you may need to re-evaluate how data is captured into the text area in the first place (for example, by explicitly including field separators - like CSV files or similar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a formula instead of a script:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2;"Email: (.*) Company name: (.*) How can we help?")
```

Place your text in A2.

Or try:

```
var re = /Email: (.*) Company name: (.*) How can we help?/;
var company = splitStr.match(re)[2];
var email = splitStr.match(re)[1];
Logger.log(company + ": " + email);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can rely on the string always containing the expected labels in the expected order, then you can use Regular Expression matching.

```
function testIt() {
    const splitStr = "First name: Peter Last name: Pan Email: Peter@pan.com Company name: someCompany How can we help? : Looking to get some app testing done across iPhone and Android devices. Job Title: Cofounder";
    const dataRegEx = /First name: (?<firstName>.*)\s+Last name: (?<lastName>.*)\s+Email: (?<email>.*)\s+Company name: (?<company>.*)\s+How can we help\? : (?<request>.*)\s+Job Title: (?<title>.*)/;
    var dataParsed = splitStr.match(dataRegEx);
    if (dataParsed) {
        console.log(dataParsed.groups);
    }
}
```

```
10:40:08 AM Info    { firstName: 'Peter',
                      lastName: 'Pan',
                      email: 'Peter@pan.com',
                      company: 'someCompany',
                      request: 'Looking to get some app testing done across iPhone and Android devices.',
                      title: 'Cofounder' }
```